# Spring 3.0 and Hibernate 3.5 integration with contextual session

Tags: spring, hibernate

I know hibernate well, and fairly Spring core, I am able to use hibernate template and hibernate dao support class to integrate both but as from hibernate 3.1 we have contextual sessions i.e. we need not to use hibernate template and hibernate dao support but when i am trying to integrate with this concept and inject the sessionFactory in my dao class everything goes write but i am trying to insert data hibernate shows the insert query but the data is not saved to database please help me what can i do.
Here is my code

```
@Transactional
 public class UserDAO {

SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void save(User transientInstance) {
    try {
        sessionFactory.openSession().save(transientInstance);
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        throw re;
    }
}
public static UserDAO getFromApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx) {
    return (UserDAO) ctx.getBean("UserDAO");
}
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}
}
```

This is my beans.xml

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
   <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="UserDAO" class="dao.UserDAO">
   <property name="sessionFactory"><ref bean="sessionFactory" /></property>
 </bean>
```

This is my main code

```
ApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
User user=new User("firstName", "lastName", "address", "phoneNo", "mobileNo", "email", "password", false, null);
SessionFactory factory=(SessionFactory)context.getBean("sessionFactory");
Session session=factory.openSession();
Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();
UserDAO ud=(UserDAO)context.getBean("UserDAO");
ud.save(user);      
tx.commit();
session.close();
```

Comment: can any one suggest the best site to learn about spring

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code,

1. The DAO is already transactional, managed by Spring. You are starting another transaction in main.
2. You are opening session twice. Once in main and another time in dao.
3. When you are using contextual session, it is best practice to call  `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`

Now if you have configured transaction manager with Spring properly, the following code will work, I just added some comments, see if it's helpful to you :)

```
@Transactional
 public class UserDAO {

SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void save(User transientInstance) {
   //Removed try-catch. It was just catching RuntimeException only to re throw it
   sessionFactory.openSession().save(transientInstance);

}
//I would get rid of this method.  
public static UserDAO getFromApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx) {
    return (UserDAO) ctx.getBean("UserDAO");
}
//I would get rid of this method or make it private  
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}
}
```

Main code

```
ApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
//I would use builder instead of constructor here
User user=new User("firstName", "lastName", "address", "phoneNo", "mobileNo", "email", "password", false, null);

UserDAO ud=(UserDAO)context.getBean("UserDAO");
ud.save(user);
```

Comment: i am a newbie to use spring but i failry know about hibernate can you please suggest me best resource to learn spring